# Packaging a pre-configured next-auth library using vite library mode

Tags: next.js, vite, next-auth, rollup

My company wants to make a pre-configured next-auth package on a private npm repo. This sounds like a great idea because I can quickly add an npm package that has next-auth already included and pre-configured out of the gate for our servers, just need to provide the  secrets.

I'm running into issues though when it comes to building the library. I have it working locally (a vanilla next project just importing the `index.ts` from the project files), but I am unable to do the same with the `dist` version.

This is my vite config for building the package

```
export default defineConfig(() => ({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        tsConfigPaths(),
        dts({ include: ['src']} ),
    ],
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: resolve('src', 'index.ts'),
            name: 'company-auth',
            formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
            fileName: (format) => `company-auth.${format === 'cjs' ? 'cjs' : 'es.js'}`,
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'next-auth'],
            output: {
                globals: {
                    react: 'React',
                    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
                    'next-auth': 'next-auth',
                },
            },
        },
        esbuild: {
            minify: true,
        },
    },
}));
```

I essentially created a preconfigured `AuthOptions` Object

```
export const CompanyAuthHandler = NextAuth({
 ... configuration
})
```

which the idea is to be used like so

```
// app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

import { CompanyAuthHandler } from '@companypackage';
export { CompanyAuthHandler as GET, CompanyAuthHandler as POST };
```

This works when testing locally, but when I build and I import it into a project, I get

```
TypeError: next_auth__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a function

------------------------------------------------------------------------
../dist/company-auth.es.js (82:11) @ Qt

  80 | }
  81 | }
> 82 | const ea = Qt({
     |         ^
  83 | pages: {
  84 |   signIn: "/login"
  85 | },
```

When I look into `company-auth.es.js` output I see this:

```
import Qt from "next-auth";

.
.
.

const ea = Qt({
  pages: { ... },
  providers: [ ... ],
  callbacks: { ... }
});
```

Which it seems `Qt` is the `NextAuth` function. I sense it has something to do with rolling up the dependcy or the way `Qt` (`NextAuth`) is exported?